# Can I change UI using Google Chrome's API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a Chrome extension that will change the Chrome GUI (i.e. add menu items, change theme values, change tab appearance etc.). Is this possible?

Comment: It's called a theme. Not an extension.

Comment: @ColeJohnson no, you completely misunderstood me. I wanna make an extension that is capable of changing the Chrome GUI, say I want to change the arrow colors etc.

Comment: Oh in that case, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I never actually dug into Chrome's source, but does it expose some sort of API to mess with its core?

Comment: I doubt it does. I too haven't looked through the source, so I can't be sure. However, there may be a way to do this; download the source, modify the graphics, then compile. However, that might not work if the images are embedded in the source as base64 strings.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, sure that's not what I want, I want users to be able to use my product. IE for instance offers some of its GUI via a public API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There are no API's that let you programmatically control menu items, themes or tab appearance.

There are declarative ways such as:

- [Override Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html) for New tab Page, History and Bookmarks
- [Themes](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes.html)

Comment: Is that still valid?